# Nuxt3 - Intlify i18n - "Must be called at the top of a `setup` function"

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

When trying to change the language in the click function, I get the error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Must be called at the top of a `setup` function (at message-compiler.mjs:54:19)".

When the same language change happens outside of the function everything works fine.

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
modules: [
  '@pinia/nuxt',
  "@intlify/nuxt3"
],
intlify: {
  localeDir: 'locales', // this the path for languages json files
  legacy: false,
  vueI18n: {
    locale: 'en',
    globalInjection: true,
  }
}
```

`languageSwitch.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const changeLanguage = (lang) => {
  useI18n().locale.value = lang
}
</script>
```

Comment: When do you have that error? In the shared snippets?

Comment: Just FYI, the developers of `@intlify/nuxt3` recommend using this instead: https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup. This is stated in the readme file https://github.com/intlify/nuxt3.

Comment: @FelixEklöf Thank you very much. I don't know how I didn't find this information about version 8+

Answer (score 0):

Create a Nuxt3 plugin and add the following:

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

  const i18n = nuxtApp.$i18n;

  const modules  = {
    i18n: i18n
  };

  return {
    provide: {
      i18n: modules,
    },
  };
});
```

You can then access your i18n Instance, example:

```
const { $api } = useNuxtApp();
$i18n.i18n.locale.value
```

Comment: why  `const { $api } = useNuxtApp();` if `$api` not used? you might wanted to say `const { $i18n } = useNuxtApp();` or I don't understand. By the way, this would work with `nuxt-i18n` V8?

Comment: gives error message: Cannot redefine property: $i18n